# iPhone - What happens if retain after autorelease?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, retain, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Do you know what happens if I retain an autoreleased object ?
Will it be released or does the retain wins ?

Comment: the simplest way to find out is to try it. modify your code, build and run. Tell us your findings. %)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do you know what happens if I retain
>   an autoreleased object ? Will it be
>   released or does the retain wins ?

The `retain` "wins" but thinking of it that way is full of fail.

retain and release are merely mechanisms via which you increase or decrease the retain count of an object.   Autorelease is simply a delayed release; no more, no less.

If you retain an autoreleased object you are increasing the retain count NOW while the retain count will be decreased LATER.   This happens all the time;  `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"...."]` returns an autoreleased string that you `retain` if you want it to stick around beyond [most typically] the current pass through the event loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your variable around, you **need** to retain it. For example:

```
myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:...] retain];
```

The `buttonWithType:` method returns a `UIButton` that's been instantiated with `autorelease`. It'll take care of releasing itself (so to speak) when needed.

Answer (score 2):

The retain will win out.  This is very common, and is an excepted practice.

Usually convenience methods return autoreleased objects like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
```

It is expected that you retain whatever objects you need to, so long as you remember to release them later.

Remember that autoreleases will happen at the end of the current system message.

From the article below:
"an autorelease pool is created for each message that is processed by the system and the objects in the pool are all automatically released after processing on that message has completed."

Some great explanations of this can be found here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7295-getters-setters-properties-newbie.html

Comment: Pretty good answer, except the autorelease doesn't (necessarily) happen at the conclusion of the current method. The autoreleased objects are only released when the pool is drained and that usually only happens once every trip through the run loop. Your autoreleased objects have the potential to stick around for a long time.

Comment: @kubi: From the article i posted "an autorelease pool is created for each message that is processed by the system and the objects in the pool are all automatically released after processing on that message has completed."  I did not mean the current message, i meant the current system message.  I'll correct my post.

Comment: "Current system message" is conceptually correct, but a more accurate term is "current event", typically "current event processed by runloop".   Note that GCD queues also manage an autorelease pool per queue (or more, in some cases), but the drain is far less deterministic than a run loop.